# Link with downloadable pdf file in Django

Tags: django

I have a pdf file in static folder {% static 'pdf/files.pdf' %}. I need to make this file downloadable by a normal link.. Anyone can give me the easiest way to do it? thanks very much

Comment: Normal link? Is link generated by static tag not normal?

Comment: I tried but all examples I found are quite complicated for a newbie as me and don't work (may be my mistakes)...Noarmal link means without having to create much complicated functions..

Answer (score 0):

Create a view action and call it on link(your download link) click then return your file.
For ex:

`def generate_PDF(request):
    file = open('test.pdf', "w+b")
    file.seek(0)
    pdf = file.read()
    file.close()
    return HttpResponse(pdf, 'application/pdf')`

Comment: Thanks..will try it.. does this need any particular import?

Comment: No need for any particular import.

Comment: ok but where to store the pdf file and how tolink it in the html page? thanks

Comment: In your project or any where but must have read write access,  file = open('your/path/file.pdf', "w+b")

Comment: so even in templates folder? Where to add this w+b parameter?